# python reverse probability look up for normal distribution

Tags: python, normal-distribution

given a normal distribution n(mio,sigma) and a probability p(X), I want to find the x.

e.g. if mio=2 and  sigma^2=5, I want to know for what x the probability is 0.2.

I know about scipy.stats.norm.pdf(X, loc=2, scale=5)=0.2, and I am looking for the reverse function.

Comment: from scipy.stats import invgauss and potentially invgauss.pdf? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.invgauss.html#scipy.stats.invgauss

Comment: I don't know how to use it. also, I am not sure if it is the function I'm looking for. 
for example, scipy.stats.norm.pdf(0.2, loc=0, scale=1)=0.3910426939754559. Is there any function f, that f(0.3910426939754559,loc=0,scale=1)=0.2?

Comment: What is your mu-value? 2?

Comment: loc(mu?) is 0, and scale(sigma) is 1. I dont know what should I set for the value of mu.

Comment: I think the loc=0 and scale=1 are already defined as the defaults for those parameters in the function, I am not sure about the mu value either, but it is distinct from loc. I think we might be looking at the wrong thing though.. I don't think the inverse should be hard to find but for some reason it is

Comment: I can write a for loop, and compare the result of scipy.stats.norm.pdf with the probability that I'm looking for. but it is weird that it is hard to find such a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy.stats.invnorm`, from the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.stats.invnorm.html)

`prb = invnorm.cdf(x,mu)`

Comment: scipy.stats.invnorm has been deprecated. Also, I am looking for invPDF, not invCDF. i don't know if there is a function for that.

Comment: A PDF has two y values for each x, you cannot really take an inverse. If you're talking about probabilities you should be dealing with the CDF (and you cannot say what is the prob of x=0.2, when you deal with a CDF you ask "what is the prob of x<0.2)